# Erlang: Parallel message passing from a List of data to to a List of Processes

Tags: erlang

How do I implement a simultaneous passing from all values in a List A, to a List of Processes B? Both List A & B are of equal size. Let's say A = [1,2,3] and B = [<0.42.0>,<0.43.0>,<0.44.0>]. I want to pass the value 1 to process <0.42.0> and so on in **parallel** execution.

Here is what I came up so far:

```
pass_values([P|ValueListA], [H|ProcessListB]) ->
    H ! {foo, P},
    pass_values(ValueListA, ProcessListB).
```

Comment: Since message passing in Erlang is asynchronous, parallel execution might not be necessary in your case.

Comment: There is no way to pass messages in parallel in Erlang. A single process is a *serially* executing entity. Is there a specific reason you want to pass messages in parallel? Because any atomicity guarantee you may want to obtain for that won't hold in Erlang too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a `scatter` utility that takes an array of elements and distributes the elements to an array of processes.

```
-module(lab).

-compile(export_all).

go() ->
    ProcessList =
        lists:map(fun(_) ->
                          spawn(?MODULE, echo, [])
                  end,
                  lists:seq(1, 6)),
    DataList = ["E", "r", "l", "a", "n", "g"],
    scatter(DataList, ProcessList).

scatter(DataList, ProcessList) ->
    lists:foreach(fun({Data, Process}) ->
                          Process ! Data
                  end,
                  lists:zip(DataList, ProcessList)).

echo() ->
    receive
        Msg ->
            io:format("~p echos ~p~n", [self(), Msg]),
            echo()
    end.
```

Give it a try:

```
1> c(lab).
{ok,lab}
2> lab:go().
<0.40.0> echos "E"
<0.41.0> echos "r"
<0.42.0> echos "l"
<0.43.0> echos "a"
<0.44.0> echos "n"
<0.45.0> echos "g"
ok
```

Comment: But this does not implement parallel message passing